# react & highcharts: add navigation button

Tags: reactjs, react-native, highcharts, navigation

How to add a navigation button in highcharts for react?

The code worked with standard Highcharts (although it was required to use additional modules/exporting).

But when I started using react and highcharts for react, the button disappeared.

```
import { Component } from 'react';

import Highcharts from 'highcharts';
import HighchartsReact from 'highcharts-react-official';

class IChartCustom extends Component {

    constructor(props: any) {
        super(props);

        this.state.options = {

            navigation: {
                buttonOptions: {
                    enabled:                    true,

                    align:                      'right',
                    verticalAlign:              'bottom',
                },
            },
        };
    }

    render() {    
        return (
            <HighchartsReact highcharts = {Highcharts} options = {this.state.options} />
        );
    }
}

export default IChartCustom;
```

[image]

Please tell me what to add to the code to make the navigation button appear

Answer (score 0):

decided :)

```
import HC_exporting from 'highcharts/modules/exporting'

...

HC_exporting(Highcharts);
```